# Delayed Offside Question (faceoff location, puck out of bounds)

Tags: rules, officiating, ice-hockey, nhl

Just FYI, I've delved into detail with this question, but for good reason. I have found it next to impossible to get this answered accurately, so I try and describe it best as I can. Thanks for reading, any of you NHL rule buffs.

The following is in the IIHF rule for delayed offside. I want to compare with the NHL interpretation. After reading the first clause for context, read "ix" and "x", both of which bring on my question. The question relates to faceoff location, which I think belongs in the defensive zone in BOTH scenarios, not just "x", under NHL rules. Could be wrong. I almost suspect I am.

"viii. If, during a delayed offside, a player from the defending team shoots the puck directly out of play, rules pertaining to delay of game will be applied and the appropriate penalty assessed.

ix. If the situation in Rule 82-viii occurs but the puck deflects off the glass or a teammate, but does not cross the blue line, no penalty will be assessed but the ensuing faceoff will be in the neutral zone because of the delayed offside."

x. If the situation in Rule 82-viii occurs but the puck deflects off the glass or a teammate but does cross the blue line, no penalty will be assessed but the ensuing faceoff will be in the defending zone on the side where the puck was shot or deflected."

Do these apply in the NHL? Specifically, "ix", since that is the one I'm quibbling over. The neutral zone draw just feels wrong to me somehow. The first one there (viii) is referenced in the NHL book, and it's the same. The others are nowhere in the rulebook unless you do some serious reading in between the lines. They do mention a couple delayed offside/puck out of bounds scenarios, but not those, and nothing that specific. Just the first one there, one about the attacking team's original shot causing the delayed offside deflecting out off a defender, a shot off the crossbar going out during a delayed offside, and a delayed penalty on the defending team during a delayed offside. In all of those situations, the faceoff is held in the neutral zone; the original shot infraction faceoff is held from the spot closest to where the shot was taken. You could apply this logic to my scenario, but I'm unsure about that.

Answer (score 0):

The first instance of
 "viii. If, during a delayed offside, a player from the defending team shoots the puck directly out of play, rules pertaining to delay of game will be applied and the appropriate penalty assessed."
is clear that with a delay of game the penalty is assessed to the defending team and the face-off should remain in the defensive zone.

The change for  X is that there is no penalty but a deflection out of bounds from the defensive team. When the puck crosses the blue line the Delayed offside is no longer in effect therefore it was a deflected shot out of bounds and the defensive team has to stay in their zone for the puck going out of play.

IX- the delayed offside call negates the position of the face-off which brings it into the neutral zone due to both teams being at "fault of error" so a neutral zone face off is taken.